# Tree Diagrams click functions conflicting

Tags: javascript, click, d3.js, tree-structure

I have two trees on the same page. The first is http://bl.ocks.org/1249394, and the other is http://bl.ocks.org/2503502. I followed the examples on these 2 links for my trees, with some alterations of course. I have included both on the same page. However the click functions seem to be conflicting. The tree at  http://bl.ocks.org/1249394 works great, but the tree at http://bl.ocks.org/2503502 generates the tree with the correct data, but then when I click the root node to collapse, the child nodes data changes to that of the child nodes data for the first tree at http://bl.ocks.org/1249394. How do I fix this conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just naming the click handlers differently? This looks like you've got identically-named functions that might be in the same scope, so you should either

- make sure each graph is in a different scope (e.g. enclose all the code for each in different functions), or
- make sure all the functions on the page have unique names, or
- both.

Comment: I have tried that, many times. It has not helped. The data shows up correctly for that tree, but only when I click it, then  it changes to the data for the other tree.

Comment: Still sounds like a scope problem. This isn't diagnosable without an example page showing both trees together and demonstrating the problem.

Comment: It is a lot of code to post, I will try resolving it by changing function and variable names. The exact javascript code from the links in my original question are included in a php document using <script>firsttree.js</script> and another for the second tree.

Comment: My point is, it's impossible to really see how the two scripts might conflict without understanding how they're both included in the page. The two likely culprits are 1) you're overwriting your `click` function, or 2) you're overwriting your data variable. But this can't be debugged without seeing both scripts in context.